# Is there a design pattern for recovery of a recursive file search in C#/F#?

Tags: c#, recursion, f#, file-search

Assuming, that I have a long running file search, which is in the core just a recursive function as shown below (1M-100M files). If my process gets killed while still scanning for files or stops for whatever reason, is there a best practice way to implement a 'persistent state storage' or 'ContinueOnFailure'-Functionality?

Or am I completely on the wrong track and something like that is not even needed or needs a totally different approach?

Asking for any advice, also unrelated to a specific programming language (implemention will be in C#/F#, if possible) and please excuse the maybe false used terms here.

Further assumptions and thoughts.
Duplicates or few missing files are not a problem. Duplicates can be filtered and missing/'not up-to-date' files are to expect, as the operation happens on a living system. For an in-memory approach i could think of a dictionary that keeps track of the 'smallest depth' completed folders.

Or breaking down the problem be iterating till a certain threshold of subsets is reached and then keeping track of each subset in a database?

Also had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334712/omit-folders-from-recursive-file-search). It this seems unpractical for larger network drives + i'm worried about the enumeration order?

```
let rec loop depth (someDir : DirectoryInfo) = 
    seq {
        yield! someDir.EnumerateFiles ()
        yield! 
            someDir.EnumerateDirectories () 
            |> Seq.collect (loop (depth + 1))
    }


let dir = DirectoryInfo "C:\\"
loop 0 dir
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have permissions to enter sub-directories or permission to read the properties of a folder you need to use a recursive method to capture the exceptions and continue.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SAveDirectoriesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error",errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and Sorry for only providing such a minimal sample, general exception handling is done. The question is more in the direction of how to mitigate vm shutdowns, hardware failures, another critiacal error that needs a hart restart of the application. But I'm also wondering what will happen (if even possible) an exception with critical impact is thrown, e.g. AccessViolationException

Comment: The exception handlers are inside the for loops so when an exception occurs you do not jump outside the for loop which allows code to continue.